# Facebook app without asking permission on load

Tags: facebook

How do I make an app that doesn't ask for permission when you load it?

Or is that impossible?  The only thing the application does is post to the user's wall, but can't I authenticate for that after they load the application?

Comment: Pretty much impossible from what I know of Facebook's API. They're using a new permission system which asks the user if they want to allow this application to access their information and post on their wall/etc. Just a question, why do you not want to authenticate with the user and post without their permission?

Comment: Wondering how this all plays out, a year later. But what I really want to know is: what are the possible things I can do in my FB iframe app without asking for permissions?

Comment: @the0ther: you'd better post it as a question.

Comment: I find the premise of this question to be in poor, poor ethical taste. End users should be prompted about the use of their private information in a _uniform_ manner. As is done with Android apps, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, not sure why others are so positive that it is not possible.

On your server side you can check through facebook api if current user granted you required permission. If not, pass some flag to your fbml where you can display permission prompt link:

```
Would you like to <fb:prompt-permission perms="publish_stream">allow us</fb:prompt-permission> to post on your wall?
```

You are not obligated to require users to authorize your app either (but you need authorization before checking for granted permissions or retreiving any user information), you can still allow users to use your app. In fact allowing users to use an app without authorization is even encouraged by facebook recommendations. For optional authorization you can put such fbml on your page:

```
<fb:if-is-app-user> 
    <fb:else><a href="http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=...&v=1.0>Would you like to authorize this app?</fb:else> 
</fb:if-is-app-user>
```

Comment: This is the solution for fbml apps, mine applies for iframe apps. I've gotten so used to doing iframe all the time I forgot about fbml :p

Comment: If it is iframe then you have full access to facebook javascript api, so you can prompt for permission from javascript.

Comment: At the time, I thought he wanted to write a malcious app. I didn't even think about this possibility. My bad. :oops:

Answer (score 1):

If you want to post to their wall via a prompt instead of requiring prior authorization, you should use the connect library. Then you can use some javascript to open the dialog.

In fact, [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045403/how-do-i-use-fb-connect-streampublish-in-an-iframe-facebook-app) gives you exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is that impossible. The only thing
>   the application is going to do is post
>   to the users wall, but can't I
>   authenticate them for that after they
>   load the application?

To publish content to users' walls, you need to have the `steam_publish` permission from them first.